# How to center NSPopover when using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

If the `NSPopover` has its `contentViewController` set to some `NSViewController` that does not use SwiftUI directly on its `view`. For instance

```swift
final class ViewController: NSViewController {
    private lazy var contentView = NSView()

    override func loadView() {
       view = contentView
    }

    init() {
       super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
       fatalError()
    }
}

let controller = ViewController()
popover.contentViewController = controller
```

It will be displayed centered.

However, if we simply change the line of the corresponding `view`:

```swift
private lazy var contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: Blah())
```

Where `Blah` is

```swift
struct Blah: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("blah")
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 600, alignment: .center)
        .background(Color.green)
    }
}
```

You can see that the view is not centralized anymore. So, how can we let the `NSViewController` centralized in relation to the `NSStatusItem` item? (In the images those are one check icon)

[image]

If you give a close look at the images, you can see that the image with the white view has the popover arrow in the middle, while the other has not.

[image]

Comment: I fail to see the error on your screenshots. The popover is aligned to the element that's presenting it, which is the expected behaviour. Unless the screenshot is meant to be part of a larger context, the popover will move itself to "fit on screen". So it's probably a positioning issue relative to the edges of your screen, rather than a programmatic issue.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I have updated the question, I hope you can understand it better now.

Comment: Interestingly, if you don't explicitly set the width, that is use the other `.frame` method, for instance like this: `.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 600, maxHeight: .infinity)`, it *will* get centered under the anchor.

Comment: Thanks so much @tromgy, you should post is as a proper answer as it's the solution to the question